# Installation guide for 14.04.3 desktop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I just downloaded Ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.
Can you guide me through the installation process.

I have no idea how to go forward with this. Also, I'm using Windows 8 and would like to dual boot with Ubuntu desktop.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

STEPS:

1. First of all you have to set up you partitions, I recommend using minitool partition manager (link: http://filehippo.com/download_minitool_partition_wizard_home_edition/),
2. making the partitions. Make an ext-4 partition (say 100gb), this is where all your files will go, and make a linux-swap partition(say 4gb)(optional) the computer will use this as virtual memory in other words it acts as ram.
3. Next download rufus usb creator (link: https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and select "bootable disk using: iso image" and provide the route to it, select your image (the ubuntu iso file), select your drive (the usb stick) press ok and wait until the process is completed.

4.One all is done (you have successfully created the partitions and the bootable usb stick is ready) shutoff the computer. Press the power button and immediately press the esc key repeatedly until a menu pops up (this may vary depending on your machine). Select boot options and then another menu showing all drives should pop up. Select your usb stick and then the grub menu should pop up. choose install (ensure that secure boot and fast boot are disabled).

5.One the installation interface loads the first few steps should be simple enough for you. When you reach the section that asks you to choose the installation option (where it says "install alongside windows"... etc) choose "something else" at the bottom. Here double click on the ext-4 partition, select the format checkbox and set mount point as "/" which means root, then hit ok.

6.From here on the rest of the installation process should be simple enough for the noobiest of users. Good Luck!!

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this [guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)
Few points:

1. If you have Windows 8 installed in EFI mode, install ubuntu in EFI
   mode.
2. Disable secure boot in BIOS
3. Disable fast boot and hiberantion in Windows
4. Use utility like [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
5. Use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) if needed.
6. If you are new to Linux , make sure you create some unused space
   from Windows disk partition utility.
7. Last but not the least - install Linux only in unused space.
8. Your wifi card may not work initially so be connected via LAN cable
9. Keep a second laptop/computer handy to do some R&D(or ask question
   here in askubuntu) in case you are stuck

Comment: Is anything wrong with the answers - why they have been voted down?